# AWS API Create instance in non default VPC

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-product-api

I am using .NET SDK for AWS and and trying to create a service that can create/mange instances. As part of this I want to create an EC2 instance in a specific VPC (non-default). There may have more then one VPC in a zone and I want to programatically be able to create/manage instances in any of the VPC rather than just the default VPC.

Is this possible? If yes how? I looked through the API docs and could not find a way to specify the VPC at the time of creation of EC2 isntance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VPC appears to be implied by the subnet-id that you specify.  If this doesn't get you there, it might at least get you an error message explaining what you've missed.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/PEC2Instance_SubnetId_NET4_5.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TEC2RunInstancesRequest_NET4_5.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/run-instance.html

From the underlying REST API:

> `SubnetId`
>
> [EC2-VPC] The ID of the subnet to launch the instance into.
>
> Type: `String`
>
> Default: `None`
>
> Required: `No`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-RunInstances.html

Comment: Thanks, I should have realised that a subnetId is the most inambigous way to specify where the instance is launched.